# Why is "little" not the correct option to fill "only ___ milk left"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, quantifiers

In Destination B2 book, these definitions are given for quantifiers *little* and *a little*:

> little: uncountable nouns, means '**not much**'
>
> a little: uncountable nouns, means '**some**'

Now, given the following sentence:

> We've only got ______ milk left so get some when you go shopping.

I choose *little* as I thought the talker meant that there's not much milk left so they needed some to be bought. But the correct answer is ***a little***.

Can someone explain why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got little milk left.

We've got *only* a little milk left.

Comment: ah, thanks! so the remarkable word here was "only".

Comment: @user3132457: But note that *We've got little milk left* would be very unlikely in conversational contexts today - it's a dated / formal / poetic / stilted usage. Personally I'd say that the same even applies (to a lesser extent) with *We've got only **a** little milk left*. You're much more likely to hear *We've got only a [little] **bit of** milk left* (where ***little*** is effectively optional).

Comment: "We've got little milk left" isn't dated/formal/poetic/stilted where I come from.  *With the snowstorm looming, the supermarket had little milk left.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Would you say *The supermarket's got little milk left*, however? I wouldn't, as the informal markers (contraction and *got*) clash with *little X left*, which I do perceive to be more formal or literary than *a little X left*.

Comment: ***They've got little money left, given all their recent expenses***. I say it's used all the time. Not everyone speaks the same way.

Comment: @Choster: *They've got little milk left* sounds natural to me.  In *There's little time remaining* **little** is not a "marker" of any kind, at least not in my Central Atlantic dialect which covers eastern Pennsylvania, southern New Jersey, Delaware and eastern Maryland and parts of eastern Virginia now.

Comment: I guess it's just my idiolect. *They've got a little milk left*, fine. *They have little milk left*, fine. But *They've got little milk left*, yeccchh. FWIW, I grew up in Southern California but have lived inside the Beltway for 20 years.

Comment: @choster: I guess it would depend on how you hear "got".   I would agree that it's not formal, but it is used so often  that I consider it neutral, not informal.

Comment: @choster: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got+little+energy+left%22&oq=%22got+little+energy+left%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4206j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8